# Running an artisan command forever with laravel forge?

Tags: php, laravel, supervisord, pubnub, laravel-forge

Can someone possibly advise how I can keep my custom artisan command running forever with the daemon?

I saw the many tutorials with queues, however it doesn't exactly fit. I am trying to accomplish "subscribe" with pubnub's php library and this seems like the best way, unless I missed something?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you seeing that the subscribe is returning (and exiting) after 5 minutes of no messages or after a message is received? If so, you just have to return true from the subscribe to keep it open. Let me know if this is the issue and I can provide further details as a formal answer.

Answer (score 3):

If you run the artisan command from the command line - it can already run indefinitely/forever. You dont need to do anything.

I have an application that has been running the one single artisan command for 97 days straight at the moment.

You then need to make sure it has not crashed for some reason, with something like [Supervisor](http://supervisord.org/), or a web monitoring service like [Eyewitness.io](https://eyewitness.io)

Comment: Hello, 2 questions about that...

1. If I exit the CLI after running the "run" command, it will continue functioning?
2. If server crashes... i'm assuming it will have to be started manually again?

Comment: 1. You cant exit the CLI - you keep it running forever. You leave that screen/process open on that user account

Comment: 2. If server crashes - you need to restart. You can have Windows/Ubuntu run the PHP command automatically on startup, so if the server is rebooted, the process starts again automatically.

Answer (score 1):

This will help you run artisan command forever

```
nohup php artisan yourcommand:abc > mylog.log 2>&1 & echo $! >> save_pid.txt
```

when you want to kill this process, get pid from save_pid.txt file

```
kill pid
```