# Laravel Forge Long Running Artisan Command with Daemon

Tags: php, bash, laravel, laravel-5.1, laravel-artisan

I've created a command in Laravel (L5) which connects to the twitter streaming API and is available by using `php artisan collect-tweets`. When I run it locally, because it's a persistent connection, it essentially runs infinitely in the terminal window. I now have deployed the app to Laravel Forge and I want it to run the command and not kill the process. I have read the answer stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26483592/running-an-artisan-command-forever-with-laravel-forge) however I want to know if there is an alternative way to run a long running (infinite) artisan command on Laravel Forge - perhaps using a Daemon Worker?

What I've tried:

1. creating a daemon via the Forge Console and executing 'mysite.co.uk/php artisan my command' (doesnt work)
2. creating a run.sh which contains php artisan collect-tweets and trying to run by creating a daemon who's command is `mysite.co.uk/run.sh`. This give me an error saying it can't find command artisan
3. giving the daemon the full path to run.sh script `/home/forge/mysite.co.uk/run.sh` which gives an error saying `Exited too quickly (process log may have details)` (classic problem...)

Any ideas how I can achieve my goal?

Answer (score 0):

I know very little about Forge, so this solution I'll propose isn't part of that layer, nor a part of the Laravel layer, but if you can get command line access, this might work.

Other messages I've seen about this mention "don't close the terminal" which is a hackish way of doing it, but in Linux there's a command called `nohup` You can find some examples if you Bing for it. Or there's [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/137759/why-use-nohup-rather-than-exec) which you might reference.

Answer (score 0):

for the first point it should be

```
php /home/forge/my-site.com/artisan my-command
```

for using it as a daemon u can for example

```
sudo /home/forge/my-site.com/node socket.js
```

Answer (score 0):

Try run a command with ampersand at the end (&). For example I run laravel echo server at the root ot the site like that:

```
node node_modules/laravel-echo-server/bin/server.js start &
```

Command starts in other process. Use kill command to stop your command or built-in commands. For example laravel echo command can be stopped with built-in command:

```
node node_modules/laravel-echo-server/bin/server.js stop
```